# Sorting by [str, datetime] in order [ascending, descending]

Tags: python

I have an object with two attributes:

```
i.member : str
i.time : datetime
```

I tried to sort using:

```
l.sort(key=lambda i: (i.member, -i.time))
```

But it tells me that `-` is invalid with `datetime` objects (which makes sense). If this were a row in a Pandas data frame, I would sort `df.sort_values(by=['member', 'time'], ascending=[True, False])` but I don't want to incur the overhead of loading it just for sorting.

I found previous questions on the topic but they only related to sorting by `datetime` (but reversed) etc with the `reverse` parameter, which only takes a boolean (regardless, it is sorting by `tuple` so I can't pass a list of booleans).

How would I do this in normal Python?

Comment: Perhaps we can use `l.sort(key=lambda i: (i.member, -i.time.timestamp())`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dates are all after 1970, you could use the [timestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) value of the date to sort on:

```
l.sort(key=lambda i: (i.member, -i.time.timestamp()))
```